# Reducing menu.add_command() clutter/repeat lines

Tags: python, syntax, widget, tkinter

I would like to do the following (just an example, the real code has more menu's and more add_command's):

```
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut",state="disabled")
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy",state="disabled")
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste",state="disabled")
editmenu.add_command(label="Delete",state="disabled")
```

But on fewer lines, In fact, just one line if possible. I have menus that are taking up a considerable amount of space in my program and would like to reduce the clutter. Plus the programmer in me sees a bunch of similar lines and feels there must be a way to reduce them.

I tried the following code to no avail; I obviously got a nameerror because label and state aren't defined...

```
for labeldic in [{label:"Cut"},{label:"Copy"},{label:"Paste"},{label:"Delete"}]: editmenu.add_command(labeldic+{state:"disabled"})
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a translation of what you wanted to do:

```
for labeldic in [{"label":"Cut"},{"label":"Copy"},{"label":"Paste"},{"label":"Delete"}]:
    labeldic.update({"state": "disabled"})
    editmenu.add_command(**labeldic)
```

There were three problems I fixed.

The first is that dictionary keys need to be quoted if they are strings. If you want a dict mapping the string `'label'` to the the string `'cut'`, you can do it using the dict literal `{'label': 'cut'}`, or else possibly with the `dict()` constructor which expands keyword arguments that way: `dict(label='cut')`. As you discovered, `{label: 'cut'}` wouldn't work, because it tries to use a variable's value for the key, but there is no such variable.

The second is that you can't merge dictionaries using the + operator. It doesn't work, unfortunately. There is, however, an [update method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) that mutates the dict it's called on. Since it doesn't return a merged dict, it can't be used inline the way you used +.

The third problem is that passing a dict is not the same as passing in keyword arguments. `foo(bar='baz')` is not the same as `foo({'bar':'baz'})`, but it *is* the same as `foo(**{'bar':'baz'})`. The `**` syntax in function calling ["unpacks"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) a dictionary into keyword arguments.

Regardless it's sort of weird style. Here's what I would do instead:

```
for label in ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Delete']:
    editmenu.add_command(label=label, state='disabled')
```

Comment: +1 on the alternate suggestion. The "labeldic" solution is ugly and hard to read -- completely negating anything gained by "removing the clutter". Except in the most performance-sensitive cases, one should always strive to make code as readable as possible.